# Append to a readable stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, stream

I'd like to read multiple objects which basically are JSON files from S3 and create a stream to copy the contents and create/upload an unique S3 file. this is my code:

```
s3.listObjects(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return callback(err)
        data.Contents.forEach((key) => {
          stream += s3.getOject({ Bucket: `${config.metadata.s3.bucket}`, Key: key })
            .createReadableStream()
            .pipe(file)
        })
      })
```

it's possible to append streams in nodejs like in this way?

Comment: I know you cannot write to a readable stream; for that you need writable, duplex, or transform; check out the docs here: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_streams

Comment: this post in documentation shows how you can pipe data from readable to writable: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/node.js/489/filesystem-i-o#t=201608031354221709678 . I assume you can do the same for transform or duplex

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-examples.html - the AWS doc says that it is possible

Comment: fileToRead -> readableStream ->writable/duplex -> fileToWrite. This is the sort of thing you can do. You cannot get data from a readableStream and directly write it to a file; a readable stream reads. Visit the docs I have linked, they explain it much better than I am. The aws docs you link uses writable streams to write data to file. Look at the section: Amazon S3: Streaming Objects to Files on Disk (getObject)

Comment: this is the flow I've in my mind. read json from S3 -> take only some properties -> create the csv -> stream the csv to S3. my problem is how to iterate and create an unique stream since I've to read multiple json file. it is possible to append to one stream?

Comment: then you could do this: S3 -> take only some properties -> create the csv -> Readstream -> WriteStream ->  S3. The link in my second comment shows how you could do that.

Comment: @DulyKinsky the write stream should go points to one file that it will be saved locally?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: but the thing I'm missing is why creating the readstream after CSV?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119044/discussion-between-mazzy-and-duly-kinsky).